# Lost Connection in iPAD & Received memory Warning

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, memory-management, memory-leaks

Lost connection to "iPad". Restore the connection to "iPad" and run "App Name” again, or if "App Name" is still > > running, you can attach to it by selecting Debug > Attach to Process > App Name.

Also i am receiving memory warning message when i am converting view to base64String continuously and also when open camera continuously and taking photo

How should I fix this problem?

Here is Follow Code :-

Here i am Converting View as a Image and Later converting into base64 String

// This string is send to Back end

```
NSString *cardViewString = [UIImage encodeToBase64String:[UIImage imageWithView:cardView] ];
```

Methods used for converting View to base64 String

```
+(NSString *)encodeToBase64String:(UIImage *)image {

    return [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64EncodingEndLineWithCarriageReturn];

}


+(UIImage *)imageWithView:(UIView *)view{

// Get a UIImage from the UIView ...

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view .bounds.size, NO, 0);

    if ([view respondsToSelector:@selector(drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates:)])
        [view  drawViewHierarchyInRect:view .bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];  // if we have efficient iOS 7 method, use it ...
    else
        [view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];         // ... otherwise, fall back to tried and true methods

    UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return viewImage;

}
```

Comment: It simply means that you're doing heavy task that leads your app to run outta memory.

Comment: As i am developing e-visiting card app for iOS how should i fix this problem any solution ? Try since 3 days to resolve this problem. Please give me any suggestion to resolve this

Comment: Without knowing what you have done, no one could suggest you. pls post your code.

Comment: Can you please check my code if any corrections are required to fix this issue.

Comment: this code seem to have no problem, but can you specify the size of your view of which you're converting it to image?

Comment: this is actually for iPad UIView size (width = 262, height = 354)

Comment: iPhone 7 Plus UIVIew size(width = 262, height = 354)

Comment: are you creating base64 string repeatedly (in a loop or something)?

Comment: Not in Loop .After click event only i am creating base64 string. If i am continuously trying to create different e-visiting card in a particular session then i am having issue